# Error configuring tor as transparent proxy with IPv6

Tags: configuration, transparent-proxy, ipv6

I'm trying to setup a Tor transparent proxy VM to work over IPv6. The Tor manual states that for the VirtualAddrNetworkIPv6 setting:

> When providing proxy server service to a network of computers using a
>   tool like dns-proxy-tor, change the IPv4 network to "10.192.0.0/10" or
>   "172.16.0.0/12" and change the IPv6 network to "[FC00]/7".

https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en

My torrc file is configured like this:

```
VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10
VirtualAddrNetworkIPv6 [FC00]/7
```

However when I try to start Tor I get this error:

```
[warn] Malformed IP "FC00" in address pattern; rejecting.
[warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Error parsing VirtualAddressNetworkIPv6 [FC00]/7
[err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Comment: update: [#19743](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/19743) is fixed in the 0.2.9.2-alpha release, see the [patch notes](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-0292-alpha-released-important-fixes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a documentation error.

This should be raised as a ticket on the [Tor Project Bug Tracker](https://trac.torproject.org). There are details on the front page for an anonymous login, if required.

I think that it *should* be of the format:

```
VirtualAddrNetworkIPv6 [FC00::]/7
```

The default value, defined in the manual page is specified, in that format, as: `[FE80::]/10`

> ```
>   VirtualAddrNetworkIPv6 [Address]/bits
>        When Tor needs to assign a virtual (unused) address because of a
>        MAPADDRESS command from the controller or the AutomapHostsOnResolve
>        feature, Tor picks an unassigned address from this range.
>        (Defaults: 127.192.0.0/10 and [FE80::]/10 respectively.)
> ```

Update: I've created a ticket for this so that it's documented on the official bug tracker: [#19743 (VirtualAddrNetworkIPv6 manpage entry correction)](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/19743)

Comment: Yep, that did it. It starts now.